# Inner Join entre dos tablas MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Estoy tratando de hacer una inner join entre dos tablas pero no lo consigo hacer, os dejo las tablas y como estoy haciéndolo:

```
**Tabla1**

IdTabla1
Nombre

**Tabla2**

Idtabla2
Idtabla1
```

........................................

```
SELECT tabla1.Nombre
FROM tabla1
INNER JOIN tabla 2
ON tabla1.nombre = tabla2.idtabla2;
```

Necesito obtener los nombres de la tabla 1 usando la idtabla1 de la tabla 2

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. De acuerdo a lo que dices, debes poner la condición así: `ON tabla1. IdTabla1 = tabla2.idtabla2` ya que ambas tablas se relacionan por el `id`, no por el `nombre` en una de ellas.

Answer (score 5):

Simplemente te has equivocado en un campo:

```
SELECT tabla1.Nombre
FROM tabla1 INNER JOIN tabla2
     ON tabla1.IdTabla1= tabla2.Idtabla1;
```